# Why Does Spark Query (Load) from Oracle Is So Slow Comparing to SQOOP?

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We found loading data with Spark's API from Oracle databases have been always slow since Spark 1.3 up to current Spark 2.0.1. The typical code is something in Java like this:

```
        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
        options.put("url", ORACLE_CONNECTION_URL);
        options.put("dbtable", dbTable);
        options.put("batchsize", "100000");
        options.put("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

        Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = sparkSession.read().options(options)
                .format("jdbc")
                .load().cache();
        jdbcDF.createTempView("my");

        //= sparkSession.sql(dbTable);
        jdbcDF.printSchema();
        jdbcDF.show();

        System.out.println(jdbcDF.count());
```

One of our members ever tried to customize this part and he improved a lot at the time (Spark 1.3.0). But some part of the Spark core code became internal to Spark so this cannot be used after the version. Also, we see HADOOP's SQOOP is much faster than Spark for this part (but it writes to HDFS, which will needs a lot of work to be converted to Dataset for Spark uses).  Writing to Oracle using Spark's Dataset write method seems to be good for us. It is puzzling why this happens!

Comment: Got the solution: options.put("batchsize", "100000") should be replaced by options.put("fetchsize", "100000").

Comment: @PauZWu : Add as a solution as it deserves

Comment: Please do @PauZWu I want to award bounty :)

Answer (score 9):

Well @Pau Z Wu already answered the question in the comments but the problem was`options.put("batchsize", "100000");` This needed to be `options.put("fetchsize", "100000");` since fetch size deals with limiting the amount of rows retrived from the database at a time and would end up making the load time faster.

More information can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/java.817/a83724/resltse5.htm

Comment: Since Pau Z Wu doesn't seem to be interested in answering bounty is yours.